# ng-click/ onclick doesn't work on button in navbar-fixed-bottom in Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, mobile-angular-ui

I am building an application with mobile angular ui. When I try to put a button at the bottom of the screen (see example) and bind an ng-click function to the button, I can't click on the button on an android device. In a browser it works. It seems that the click-area is under the button. When I make the .navbar-fixed-bottom position:relative (it's not at the bottom), but then the button works.

Later it seemed that onclick also doesn't work.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:5px;">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="start()">
                start
         </button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by placing the navbar outside of the app-body.